# MobileFirst 8.0 server reply APP_USER_CONFIGURATION was not found

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Good Day,

There are errors accessing adapter from mobilefirst 8.0, In my App Ionic android, I submitted the parameter username and password using WL.Client.createSecurityCheckChallengeHandler(this.userLoginSecurity);
and using example adapter from Github UserLogin. I had done mfpdev app pull and mfpdev app push. But i still getting errors:

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE3002E: The resource is not found.
FWLSE3002E: The resource is not found.
[ERROR   ] Exception http://localhost:9080/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters/liveUpdateAdapter while redirecting request to http://localhost:9080/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters/liveUpdateAdapter
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID admin. An invalid user ID or password was specified.
[ERROR   ] CNFSRVE118: attachment 'configuration' for configuration id 'a94638f1-1870-4a0e-9b06-b3c6d8b5db79', schema 'mfp_default_schema', version '1.0' not found
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID push. An invalid user ID or password was specified.
[WARNING ] The deployable with name and type com.ionicframework.Xyzmobileionic708687$android$0.0.1||APP_USER_CONFIGURATION was not found.
[ERROR   ] CNFSRVE118: attachment 'configuration' for configuration id 'a94638f1-1870-4a0e-9b06-b3c6d8b5db79', schema 'mfp_default_schema', version '1.0' not found
[4/18/17 10:55:05:017 SGT] 0000036f com.ibm.utils.Log  E CNFSRVE118: attachment 'configuration' for configuration id 'a94638f1-1870-4a0e-9b06-b3c6d8b5db79', schema 'mfp_default_schema', version '1.0' not found
[4/18/17 10:55:26:798 SGT] 00000492 com.ibm.mobile.analytics.server.util.HealthStatus I VCAP_APPLICATION is not set.
```

Supposedly there is no errors on adapter and also App. Can anyone help me.

The logic are written in TypeScript. Does this problem about security settings.

Comment: If you were to do the application registration manually - in the browser, does this work or do you get the same error message?

Comment: hi vivin K - i still get this errors :[4/18/17 15:53:14:890 SGT] 00000190 y.authentication.jaas.modules.UsernameAndPasswordLoginModule A CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID admin. An invalid user ID or password was specified.
[4/18/17 15:54:59:073 SGT] 00000214 m.mfp.server.registration.internal.rest.RegistrationEndpoint E Failed to process registration request.
com.ibm.mfp.server.security.shared.MFPRESTException: 400; headers=[]; body={ errorCode=APPLICATION_DOES_NOT_EXIST errorMsg=Application doesn't exist}

Comment: "APPLICATION_DOES_NOT_EXIST errorMsg=Application doesn't exist". Can you please do a "mfpdev app register" first?

Comment: I had done the registration "mfpdev app register", but the errors come out , [ERROR   ] CNFSRVE118: attachment 'configuration' for configuration id 'c3505561-5327-4e71-841a-4267a807dcf9', schema 'mfp_default_schema', version '1.0' not found
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID admin. An invalid user ID or password was specified.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID push. An invalid user ID or password was specified.

Comment: CNFSRVE118: attachment 'configuration' for configuration id '2f888d8d-bb7d-409c-bbbd-6864ca85ab23', schema 'mfp_default_schema', version '1.0' not found
[4/19/17 11:51:44:029 SGT] 000007ed com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.v2.AdapterService                 E FWLSE3002E: The resource is not found.

Comment: Does i need to add setting header Credential Client on app Ionic , seems the errors are Authentication did not succeed for user ID push. An invalid user ID or password was specified.  How to declare it in app Client.